# Difference between look at something up close and closely

Tags: difference

- Now that I could see him **close up**, I saw that he was very attractive. (a stand-alone sentence extracted from the Longman dictionary)
- Now that I could see him **closely**, I saw that he was very attractive. (Made up by me)

Would changing to closely change the meaning of the sentence?

Another example,

- I feel intimidated whenever he comes **close** to me. (Made up by me)
- I feel intimidated whenever he comes **up close**. (Made up by me)
  Again, is there anything special about up close as compared to close/closely?

Comment: **Closely** can refer to physical nearness (closely spaced), but with verbs of seeing such as **look closely** it usually implies watching something intently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To "look close up" is to get physically near to something when examining it. To "look closely" is to examine it very carefully. Not necessarily literally from a small distance. You could say, "I looked closely at the Moon."

The sentence, "Now that I could see him closely ..." is an unlikely thing for a fluent speaker to say. You might say "Now that I could see him close up ..." or "Now that I had examined him closely ..."

Comment: Can you say "now that I could examine him closely" as well? Or would the perfect tense make more sense?

Comment: Yes, you could say that.